# How to convert string to integer in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to convert a time (hour and minute) based string to integer in puppet.
It works fine most of the time except when the minute is less than 10, say 08. For those values it throws an exception.

```
Error: Evaluation Error: The value '08' cannot be converted to Numeric.
```

Code used

```
$minute_string = Timestamp.new.strftime("%M")
#Tried the following and it did not work
#$minute_integer = $minute_string + 0
#Subsequently, attempted the following but it did not work either
$minute_integer = Integer($minute_string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like issue [PUP-6010](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-6010).  That was closed as "won't do", but the comments provide an explanation and workaround.

In brief, Puppet uses exactly the same rules to convert numeric strings to numbers that it uses to convert numeric literals, and those include that a leading `0x` directs interpretation as hexadecimal, and otherwise a leading `0` directs interpretation as octal.  Some other languages, such as Ruby and C, have the same convention.  But '8' and '9' are not valid octal digits, so the strings `'08'` and `'09'` cannot be converted directly to integers by arithmetic operators or the `Integer()` constructor.

The recommended solution is to use the `scanf` function to convert your strings:

```
$minute_integer = $minute_string.scanf('%d')[0]
```

With that format, all digits will be interpreted as decimal, and leading zeroes have no special significance.  The function returns an array, of which the `[0]` of course selects the element at index 0.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong but I receive error : Error: Evaluation Error: Comparison of: Array > Integer, is not possible. Caused by 'Only Strings, Numbers, Timespans, Timestamps, and Versions are comparable'.

Comment: Attempted a few other variations but they failed
scanf("$minute_string","%i")
scanf("$minute_string","%d")

Comment: @souser, it looks like I didn't pay enough attention to the specifics of the context in issue PUP-6010.  `scanf` returns an array, which did not present a problem in that context, but in yours, you should use the indexing operator to select the first element of that array (updated).

Comment: This is the appropriate recommended answer, and is referenced in puppetlabs documentation  (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_data_number.html#reference-5590)  You may also perform a math function, such as $int = $string + 0  to get an integer.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to add the **-** which does *not* pad it with a zero. But checking to see if John's solution will work.

```
$minute_string = Timestamp.new.strftime("%-M") ; notice("Current minute : $minute_string")
```

Accepted John's answer

Answer (score 1):

One can always use the "+ 0" trick:

```
$eleven_from_string = "11" + 0
```

Also works for decimal numbers, using "+ 0.0".